# Get absolute days away

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I want to get the absolute days away a datetime is from today.  For example, i would like to know if a date is 2 days away, or 78 days away, or even 5,239 days away (not likely, but you get the idea).  I am using an MS SQL database which is returning datetimes where the time components are all 00:00:00.

date_diff returns relative values that you then have to do some crazy math with to get absolute dates do to calculating months, years, etc.

Also, i am having issues getting the date component only of today's date in php.

Edit:
Thanks to mr. w. This is what i ended up with:

```
    $date = $row['AirdateDateTime'];
    $today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
    $away = date_diff($today, $date);
    $d = $away->format("%R%a");
```

The date_create() part was the part i was originally missing to convert to an actual datetime. Also, the format needs to be `%R%a`. Using `%R%d` only works for dates in this month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date_diff() function (really, the DateTime::diff() method) is what you want, and it's actually not hard. In fact, I think the example in the docs is exactly what you're after:

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
?>
```

What's returned is a DateInterval object, which you can format any way you want with its format() method. Above, it's being formatted to days, but you have a ton of options; see http://us.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php.

You shouldn't need to do any math yourself.

[EDIT - forgot this part]

As for getting the date component of today's date, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d');
?>
```

See http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: I was using this method before, but hadn't tried out the format method. My goal is to get a signed integer out of it. I assume I can slightly modify this code and get it to work

Comment: The %R token puts a '+' or '-' in front of the days value, so the output might be something like "+3 days" or "-2 days". If you only want the sign when it's negative, use a lowercase 'r' (i.e., "%r%d days"). If you don't want the label part, just stick to "%R%d" or "%r%d".

Comment: Thats what i figured. This worked, thanks. The full code i used is in my post if anyone is interested.  As far as the 2nd part of your post, i had already tried it, but it doesnt work, you need date_create() in front of it.  I also tried getdate() but that wasn't working either.

Comment: I just realized this is still incorrect due to a slight formatting bug: the format needs to be `%R%a`. Using `%R%d` only works for dates in this month.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
$date1 = new DateTime('2012-10-28 00:00:00',new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$date2 = new DateTime('2012-10-28 03:00:00',new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
$format = '%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds, %a total days %R';
echo $interval->format($format);
```

if want to change the format try this
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is

```
<?php

$yourDate = '2010-10-05';
echo ciel((strtotime($yourDate) - time()) / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Comment: You see, this is similar to the problems i was having. This returns "3", but that date is only 2 days away. Or more precisely -2 days away.

Comment: True. This function will be correct if you replace the round() with floor() and multiply the result by -1, OR replace the order of the arguments and replace round() with ceil().

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to convert to unix timestamps (seconds since 1970) and then get the difference.

`strtotime() and time()` are your friends.

Comment: The only issue here is timezones and DST, but sensible databases only contain UTC datetimes anyway (and possibly a timezone offset in a separate column).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what has already been suggested is the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$today = new DateTime($today);
$future = new DateTime('2010-10-25');
$interval = $today->diff($future);
echo $interval->format('%d days away'); //outputs 17 days away
```

Comment: does this work for something 45 days away, or would it just print 15?

Comment: It's going to return whatever the difference is - it's calculated at runtime. The %d gets replaced with the difference as measured in days; for other units, use other tokens. The docs I referenced in my answer give the details on this.

Comment: Why would it just print `15` ?

Comment: I was thinking it would return 15 because $interval->d returns 15, as in 15 days plus 1 month.

Comment: Not to say I told you so, but I was right. Change that date to `'2010-11-25'` and your result will be 18 days. The format needs to be `%a`

Comment: Oh I see what you were trying to say earlier regarding the `15`. Yes, my answer will only specify days within the respective month. So, your options are either specifying a month `%m` or as you have already figured out the `%a` format.